# Gvim cannot execute :python nor :python3. Windows7, Python33

Tags: python, windows, vim

I installed Gvim on my windows 7. When I type
`:python print hello`
I got the following errors
[image]

Similarly, when I type
`:python3 print hello`
The errors change to
[image]

The version information of the Gvim I installed is
[image]

And my python is version 3.3.2. I already put the path `C:\Python33\DLLs` to my `$Path` environment variable. In the DLLs directory, there is a `python3.dll`

Any help is appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like either your Gvim was not build with python/python3 or it really can't find python32.dll.

1. in the output of `:version` do you see `+python` and/or `+python3`?
2. where is `python32.dll` located on your system? (you mentioned `python3.dll` but not `python32.dll` which is what it is looking for)

If the problem is #1 then [How to enable Python support in gVim on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718122/how-to-enable-python-support-in-gvim-on-windows) might be helpful.

Comment: Maybe I have to compile and build the gvim on my windows. :-(
1. There is no +python nor +python3 in the output of :version
2. No. There is no python32.dll.
Thank you. :-)

Comment: I believe you will have seen a `-python` and `-python3` in the output correct (just checking that we are looking at the same thing). Editing my answer with link to hopefully helpful info.

Comment: I double checked, no python or python3. I am confused how the vim is integrated with python. Why this integration cannot be configured by commands, e.g., in vimrc?

Comment: Some integrations need to be compiled into the executable. Python and Ruby are examples of those. That is an issue of how VIM was written (for better or for worse).

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed 64 Bit Python? If so, you might face such issues. I had faced similar issues so, I removed 64 Bit Python and installed 32 Bit python and it worked.

On the other hand, if you have to absolutely work with 64 Bit Python, try using a 64 Bit Vim Version - You can try out this link. http://solar-blogg.blogspot.com.au/p/vim-build.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to put this in your path: `C:\Python33` NOT `C:\Python33\DLLs`