# GVim does not launch after installing plugins (Windows)

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I installed Vim 7.4 in a Windows 8 machine and it was working fine. After installing all plugins in my .vimrc, GVIM crashed and it wouldn't open again. I could manage to use VIM from `cmd` but not without some errors. My first try was to reeinstall GVIM completely. After reinstalling, it worked fine but if I also reinstall my plugins it would crash and not open again. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I removed all plugins and installed one by one until I got the error, which was with the Ultisnips plugin. I happen to know that this plugin requires VIM with Python support, which my VIM probably wouldn't have. To test this, run `vim --version` and look for a `+python` (or run `echo has("python")` from inside GVIM and look for a output of 1). In my case, it was `-python`, which was confusing, since I have Python installed. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4718183/1814970), you need to install Python after installing VIM, so I did it and it worked.